# ToolBar with EditText and Floating Button

Tags: android, toolbar, shrink

I Have added edit text to  ToolBar. Now i Want to Shrink EditText to a limit when scrolled. Floating Button Should always be visible.

When Not Scrolled
[image: When Not Scrolled]

When Scrolled
[image: When List Scrolled]

Below are the file contents

Main XML File

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="56dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lNameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fNameLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ltitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Title"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lNameLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fNameLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ldesc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Description"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/add_task_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
ToolBar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for collapsing toolbar layout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog

Basically your compressed view will be the default toolbar the extended one will be the collapsing toolbar layout. This tutorial is pretty good http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. Floating button is hiding when scrolled. Edittext is hiding. I am using Collapsing toolbar and AppLayout

Comment: I have edited question and added my xml and java code. Please check it